# Не уменьшается картинка celery django thumbnails?

Tags: django, celery, thumbnails

Делаю запрос на уменьшение картинки через rest api, все работало до использования celery, теперь размеры картинки изменются в админке, но реальное изображение не меняется на странице

tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def update_image(path, width, heigth):
    image = Image.open(path)
    output_size = (width, heigth)
    image.thumbnail(output_size)
    image.save()
```

models.py:
from .tasks import update_image

```
class Content(models.Model):

width = models.IntegerField()
heigth = models.IntegerField()
image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    update_image.delay(self.image.path, self.width, self.heigth)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ContentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    width = serializers.IntegerField()
    heigth = serializers.IntegerField()


    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Content.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.width = validated_data.get('width', instance.width)
        instance.heigth = validated_data.get(
            'heigth', instance.heigth)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py(put):

```
 def put(self, request, pk):
        saved_content = get_object_or_404(Content.objects.all(), pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('content')
        serializer = ContentSerializer(
            instance=saved_content, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            content_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "success": "Picture '{}' updated successfully".format(content_saved.id)
        })
```

Comment: В логах воркера что написано?

Comment: image.save()
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

Comment: Ну вот вам и ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: А что это значит и как это исправить(что за аргумент вообще такой)?

Comment: А это уже читайте документацию Pillow про сохранение картинок, ибо Celery тут ни при чём

Comment: Хорошо спасибо)

Comment: Вообще, если у вас раньше был какой-то код, который работал, значит вы можете в нём посмотреть, как там был написан save

Comment: точно так же, только я не передавал его в таск и все делалось в модели

Comment: Task pictures.tasks.update_image[a1088d3b-7921-4b83-8a7a-af3236065e9d] succeeded in 0.031000000000858563s: None. Теперь пишет такое сообщение, ошибки нет и результата тоже, видимо просто надо было перезапустить celery

Comment: Такая глупая ошибка, аргумент fp это оказывается путь к файлу, т.е. нужно прописать image.save(path)